# How to get dictionaries data once for all components in module in Angular 7

Tags: angular, api, lazy-loading

I am looking for the best solution for case as getting some dictionaries which are reusable in some components.

I am using lazy loading module with different components used in different routes. I am thinking of getting those dictionaries somewhare in module. But I don't want to set it as parameter in html where I use my components. Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a service, where you can manage all interactions with your dictionaries (load from api, store service property etc.). For example it can be like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class DictionaryService {

  private dictionary = null;
  constructor() { }

  getDictionary() {
    if (!this.dictionary) {
      this.fetchDictionary();
    }

    return this.dictionary;
  }

  private fetchDictionary() {
    //load dictionary from somewhere you stored it and put result in this.dictionary property
  }
}
```

After you can call your service in component:

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public dictService: DictionaryService) {}

  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

Make service property in component with access modificator public, to get access to it methods in template directly.

Comment: yeah - but if I think well this mean that I have to declare in every single component where I am using these data. Am I right?

Comment: Just inject in components where you need your service like  constructor(public dictService: DictionaryService) {}